# Remove indoor maps from styled Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make a styled google map with just the Boston subway lines, land, and water. I set the visibility of everything to off, but some buildings are still showing up, and it looks like its only buildings with indoor maps.

Here is my code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var lat = 42.3581;
    var long = -71.0636;
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

    function initialize()
    {
        var mapStyle =
        [
            {
                featureType: 'administrative',
                elementType: 'all',
                stylers:
                [
                    { visibility: 'off' }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'landscape',
                elementType: 'all',
                stylers:
                [
                    { visibility: 'off' }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'poi',
                elementType: 'all',
                stylers:
                [
                    { visibility: 'off' }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'road',
                elementType: 'all',
                stylers:
                [
                    { visibility: 'off' }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'transit',
                elementType: 'all',
                stylers:
                [
                    { visibility: 'off' }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'water',
                elementType: 'all',
                stylers:
                [
                    { visibility: 'off' }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'landscape',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers:
                [
                    { color: '#ffffff' },
                    { visibility: 'on' }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'water',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers:
                [
                    { color: '#e5e5e5' },
                    { visibility: 'on' }
                ]
            }
        ];

        var mapOptions =
        {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            zoom: 16,
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            panControl: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            scrollwheel: true,
            draggable: true
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
        var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();
        transitLayer.setMap(map);
        var styledMapOptions = {name: 'Map'};
        var newMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(mapStyle, styledMapOptions);
        map.mapTypes.set('stylized', newMapType);
        map.setMapTypeId('stylized');

        onResize();
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    function onResize()
    {
        document.getElementById("map-canvas").style.height = window.innerHeight - document.getElementById("map-canvas").getBoundingClientRect().top + 24 +"px";
    }

    </script>

</head>

<body onResize="onResize()">
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
</body>

</html>
```

I also tried this, which worked but it turned my transit layer off too, and I need the transit layer for the colored subway lines:

```
featureType: 'all',
elementType: 'all',
stylers:
[
    { visibility: 'off' }
]
```

Comment: If you ever found a fix for this, please post the answer and mark as solved.

Comment: I never found a solution.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I found to achive this, is to disable everything and then putting each major style section back to visible afterwards in the styles json.

You can use the following as a reset styles json to remove indoor maps

```
[
  {"stylers": [ {"visibility": "off" } ] },
  {"featureType": "water","stylers": [{"visibility": "on"} ] },
  {"featureType": "poi","stylers": [ {"visibility": "on"} ]},
  {"featureType": "transit","stylers": [{ "visibility": "on"}] },
  { "featureType": "landscape","stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" } ] },
  { "featureType": "road", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" } ] },
  { "featureType": "administrative",  "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" } ] },
  /* followed by your style if you have specific styles
    , otherwise remove the last comma */

]
```

Comment: Like I said, this works, but it turned my transit layer off too, and I need the transit layer for the colored subway lines.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
{
    featureType: 'indoor',
    stylers:
    [
        { visibility: 'off' }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of this response, there is no way to disable indoor maps. It is yet to be added to the style API.

However, as mentioned above, disabling all geometry will remove indoor maps as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue where if I zoomed in to much, the [interiors of buildings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmEhk.jpg) started to show that was conflicting with the styles I had set. I was able to solve this and get rid of the interiors by using Google's [Style Map Wizard](http://googlemaps.github.io/js-samples/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) and started by adding a layer with everything turned off. Then layer by layer adding what I needed (road geometry, landscape, etc.).