# Google Maps JavaScript API - Styling Buildings

Tags: javascript, google-maps, styles

Here's the problem I have:

[image]

I have a styled Google Maps displayed. I can't seem to get the university's buildings to be uncolored and stroked like the rest of the buildings. I have looked at the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType

and have tried them all but none of them work.

Here's my style:

```
[
   {
      "featureType":"water",
      "elementType":"geometry",
      "stylers":[
         {
            "color":"#193341"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "featureType":"landscape",
      "elementType":"geometry.fill",
      "stylers":[
         {
            "color":"#2c5a71"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "featureType":"landscape",
      "elementType":"geometry.stroke",
      "stylers":[
         {
            "color":"#2c5a71"
         },
         {
            "lightness":-50
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "featureType":"road",
      "elementType":"geometry",
      "stylers":[
         {
            "color":"#29768a"
         },
         {
            "lightness":-37
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "featureType":"poi",
      "elementType":"geometry",
      "stylers":[
         {
            "color":"#406d80"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "featureType":"transit",
      "elementType":"geometry",
      "stylers":[
         {
            "color":"#406d80"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "elementType":"labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers":[
         {
            "visibility":"on"
         },
         {
            "color":"#3e606f"
         },
         {
            "weight":2
         },
         {
            "gamma":0.84
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "elementType":"labels.text.fill",
      "stylers":[
         {
            "color":"#ffffff"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "featureType":"administrative",
      "elementType":"geometry",
      "stylers":[
         {
            "weight":0.6
         },
         {
            "color":"#1a3541"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "featureType":"poi",
      "elementType":"labels",
      "stylers":[
         {
            "visibility":"off"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "featureType":"poi.park",
      "elementType":"geometry",
      "stylers":[
         {
            "color":"#2c5a71"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "featureType":"landscape",
      "elementType":"geometry",
      "stylers":[
         {
            "hue":"#406d80"
         },
         {
            "gamma":1
         },
         {
            "lightness":1
         },
         {
            "saturation":0
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "featureType":"poi",
      "elementType":"geometry",
      "stylers":[
         {
            "visibility":"off"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Is it even possible to change those building colors?

Answer (score 0):

The buildings on your map that aren't getting styled are all showing indoor maps. I think what you want to do is to style indoor maps.

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to restyle indoor maps. The closest thing I can find is:

[Remove indoor maps from styled Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416261/remove-indoor-maps-from-styled-google-maps)

The suggested solution there is:

```
[
  {"stylers": [ {"visibility": "off" } ] },
  {"featureType": "water","stylers": [{"visibility": "on"} ] },
  {"featureType": "poi","stylers": [ {"visibility": "on"} ]},
  {"featureType": "transit","stylers": [{ "visibility": "on"}] },
  { "featureType": "landscape","stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" } ] },
  { "featureType": "road", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" } ] },
  { "featureType": "administrative",  "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" } ] },
  /* followed by your style if you have specific styles
    , otherwise remove the last comma */

]
```